# java: downloading a file sometimes occurs IOException: invalid http response

Tags: java, http, url, download

The following code is one of the functions in my program:

```
public void download(String url) throws IOException{
    URL website = new URL(url);
    ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.csv");
    fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
```

**Problems**:

Sometimes it works and downloads the file.

But sometimes it just downloads the file and nothing inside.

Also sometimes, it will happen to be exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1555)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at linkproject.Link.download(Link.java:65)
    at linkproject.Link.continualDownload(Link.java:158)
    at linkproject.Link.main(Link.java:183)
```

"link project" is just my main program.

PS: In my program, I will change the URL for every 5 seconds. After that I will call the download function. So sometimes it will happen to be exception, I'm very confused about that.
Like my URL here is: 
http://www.taifex.com.tw/chinese/3/7_12_8dl.asp?syear=2015&smonth=10&sday=16&eyear=2015&emonth=10&eday=16&COMMODITY_ID=TXF

And every time I change the value of sday, smonth, syear and so on.

I want to figure out why it will occur exception and how can I fix it.

Comment: It likely does that because the server is not responding correctly.

Comment: ... or there is a network problem.

Comment: @Thilo No. A network problem would manifest itself differently.

Comment: @EJP: "sometimes it just downloads the file and nothing inside". I think that could happen due to network problem. (Not that specific exception, though, that also "sometimes happens")

Comment: i see. based on you guys comments. I think I will just check the network in the code every time I download the file. For instance, I will check whether the file is empty, and also catch the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I think I think of a solution to solve that.
Based on all the comments you guys posted, I simply catch the IOException and run the code again until no exception.
Furthermore, once it happens to be IOException then I will sleep for 1 or 2 seconds to avoid many times concurrent connections.

For the problem of "nothing inside", I check the content and if it is null. Then I will download it again util something useful inside.

Turns out it works fine. BTW, thanks all you guys' comments.